# Static Linking dependencies

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, static-libraries

I'm trying to build a app which is linked against a bunch of static and shared libraries. Which is done by following command :

```
arif@khost:~/sak/pjsip$ gcc -v -o /home/arif/pjsip-samples/sample_apps/playfile.out pjsip-apps/src/samples/playfile.o `pkg-config --libs libpjproject`
```

Where `pkg-config --libs libpjproject` spits out :

```
    arif@khost:~/sak/pjsip$ pkg-config --libs libpjproject
    -pthread -L/opt/pjsip/lib -L/opt/ffmpeg/lib -lpjmedia-videodev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjmedia-audiodev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjmedia-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
............(other libraries are omitted)
```

The relevant libraries are 
[1]`pjmedia-audiodev` 
[2]`pjmedia

The linking error which is reported here :

```
/opt/pjsip/lib/libpjmedia-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a(endpoint.o): In function `pjmedia_endpt_create':
endpoint.c:(.text+0x14f): undefined reference to `pjmedia_aud_subsys_init'
endpoint.c:(.text+0x1b0): undefined reference to `pjmedia_aud_subsys_shutdown'(etc)
```

Now it should not be the case because :

```
arif@khost:~/sak/pjsip$ nm /opt/pjsip/lib/libpjmedia-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a | grep pjmedia_aud_subsys
                 U pjmedia_aud_subsys_init
                 U pjmedia_aud_subsys_shutdown
                 U pjmedia_aud_subsys_get_pool_factory
                 U pjmedia_aud_subsys_init
                 U pjmedia_aud_subsys_shutdown

`
```

I'm aware of the fact that **linking order** is very important for shared libraries, I thought it should not be the case because we are copying the object file anyway.

Am i missing something?

**UPDATE 1**

My bad, The symbol is not in pjmedia but in pjmedia-auddev :

```
arif@khost:/opt/pjsip/lib$ nm -C libpjmedia-audiodev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a | grep pjmedia_aud_subsys_init
0000000000000720 T pjmedia_aud_subsys_init
```

So there is clearly linking order problem here. Because `libpjmedia` using `libpjmedia-auddev` but in command line its given in wrong order.

The problem is solved if i take `libpjmedia` before `libpjmedia-auddev`.

Comment: *linking order* is also important for static libraries, and more generally is almost always important...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
         U pjmedia_aud_subsys_init
```

`U` in this output means that the symbol is undefined. When it's defined in this library, this column of output should have `t` or `T`, and address of the symbol is output on the left.

You should find the library which actually defines these symbols and add it to command line.

Answer (score 0):

You need **-lpjmedia-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu** before **-lpjmedia-videodev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu** inclusion.